# Why does Ruby's Time class allow invalid dates like February 30?

Tags: ruby, date, time

When you try:

```
Time.new(2016, 2, 30)
```

it will return the next valid date instead:

```
2016-03-01 00:00:00 +0900
```

I expected an error because 2016-02-30 is not a valid date.

Is this a bug?

Comment: [2016 year has only 29 days in the February month.](http://www.timeanddate.com/calendar/monthly.html%3Fmonth%3D2%26country%3D1) It's not a bug, it is feature.

Comment: please check your date, you are passing 30th Feb 2016, how is it possible?

Comment: yeah i was wondering too. i try in irb and that odd happend. it supposed to be failed or something but..

Comment: i update my post : 2016-2-30 is not supposed exist but in irb it will return next month instead.

Comment: It exist but not in 2016 year.

Comment: so 2016-2-30 is not supposed exist but, it will return next month instead.

Comment: @IrfandiAchmad What do you expect should happen? What does the documentation say should happen? How do other languages/libraries behave, for comparison? I don't understand what your question/complaint is.

Comment: it should be errors/failure, but it return 2016-03-01 00:00:00 +0900 instead..

Comment: @Зелёный February 30 does _not_ exist :-)

Answer (score 0):

`Time.new` seem to check only if the day value is between 1 and 31. I'm not sure if this is a bug or feature. At least it is inconsistent.

You could use [`Date.valid_date?`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-c-valid_date-3F) to validate the date:

```
Date.valid_date?(2016, 2, 30) #=> false
Date.valid_date?(2016, 2, 29) #=> true
Date.valid_date?(2015, 2, 29) #=> false
Date.valid_date?(2015, 2, 28) #=> true
```

Likewise, [`Date.new`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-c-new) raises an `ArgumentError` if a date is invalid:

```
Date.new(2016, 2, 30) #=> ArgumentError: invalid date
Date.new(2016, 2, 29) #=> #<Date: 2016-02-29 ...>
```

Comment: currently i tried make Time class to override the Time#initialize function and then use super inside of initialize. is it possible?

Comment: It's probably possible, but you should not modify Ruby's core classes.

Comment: Choosing Time.new over Date.new means you get time at 12:00 AM. Even if the date is invalid, you'd get the time on a valid date corresponding to a proper counting of date. Date.new throws an error for invalid date because the interest is date and not time.